# jQuery: array of elements to raw html?

Tags: jquery, element, documentfragment

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
var content = [ $('<p>...</p>'), $('<p>...</p>') ];
```

I need to get the markup of the concatenated elements. So I need to convert `content`" into a raw string: "`<p>...</p><p>...</p>`".

How can this easily be done? Seems like there should already be something in the framework to do this.

Somehow maybe convert `content` into a document fragment and call `.html()` on the document fragment to get the markup?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking to do here. Are you looking to simply iterate over the array and build a string that is the array elements concatenated together? In that case, you are probably looking to use the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function. I apologise if I have misunderstood you, but it is not entirely clear what you mean to me.

Answer (score 16):

Nothing automatic, but you could easily do what you just described.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y5x5z/

```
var content = [ $('<p>...</p>'), $('<p>...</p>') ];

var container = $('<div/>');

$.each(content, function(i,val) {
    container.append(val);
});

alert(container.html());
```

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
- http://api.jquery.com/append/
      ​

Comment: Try  `$.fn.append.apply($('<div>'),  content).html()`

Answer (score 3):

This is shorter than the other answers, works correctly, and does not use an explicit loop:

```
[$("<p>"), $("<p>")].map(function(el){return el.get()[0].outerHTML;})
```

As Crazy Train points out in the comments, this can be sugared-up as follows:

```
var content = [ $('<p>...</p>'), $('<p>...</p>') ];

$.fn.toString = function() {
    return this[0].outerHTML
};

alert(content.join("")); // <p>...</p><p>...</p>
```

Comment: `.map()` is just as much of a loop as `$.each()` is. :P Any solution will ultimately loop the Array content at some level, but here's a trick that conceals it pretty well. http://jsfiddle.net/Y5x5z/4/

Comment: If your element array is from an actual jQuery collection (say, result of $('li') selector), you'll have to do 
`$.makeArray(content).join('')`;

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same type of task and today's way of doing this is simple:

```
const elements = [$('<p>...</p>'), $('<p>...</p>')];
const resultString = elements.reduce(
  (HTMLString, [element]) => HTMLString.concat(element.outerHTML),
  '',
);
```

Notice that `HTMLString`'s default value in `reduce` is `''`. It's important for `HTMLString` to be a type of string to be able to concatenate HTML strings of elements to it.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old post someone may stumble upon it like me... the correct way to do it would be [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) (standard JavaScript not jQuery)

```
var content = [ $('<p>...</p>').html(), $('<p>...</p>').html() ];

var concatenatedHTML = content.join('');

//concatenatedHTML would then be '<p>...</p><p>...</p>'
```

Comment: Did you actually try running this bro?  'cause it don't work.

Comment: @g33kz0r I guess you are right - updated it. The solution is not ideal but it does now work.